# Calculating new rows in the DF from existing rows

Tags: r, dplyr

I would like the df_final outcome below.  In order to achieve it I need to calculate the 'Final' row and add to the df.  Code below:

```
Short_Name <- c("BE", "BE", "DE", "DE", "BE", "BE", "DE", "DE")
Long_Name <- c("BELGIUM", "BELGIUM", "GERMANY", "GERMANY", "BELGIUM", "BELGIUM", "GERMANY", "GERMANY")
Short_date <- c("Jan 22", "Jan 22", "Jan 22", "Jan 22","Feb 22", "Feb 22","Feb 22", "Feb 22")
Long_date <- c("1/1/2022", "1/1/2022", "1/1/2022", "1/1/2022", "2/1/2022", "2/1/2022", "2/1/2022", "2/1/2022")
Category <- c("Original", "Discount", "Original", "Discount","Original", "Discount",
```

"Original", "Discount")
Amount <- c(100, 20, 90, 10, 120,40, 80, 15)
df_original <- data.frame(Short_Name, Long_Name, Short_date, Long_date, Category, Amount)

```
Short_Name <- c("BE", "BE", "BE", "DE", "DE","DE","BE", "BE", "BE", "DE", "DE", "DE")
Long_Name <- c("BELGIUM", "BELGIUM", "BELGIUM", "GERMANY", "GERMANY", "GERMANY","BELGIUM", "BELGIUM", "BELGIUM", "GERMANY", "GERMANY", "GERMANY")
Short_date <- c("Jan 22", "Jan 22", "Jan 22", "Jan 22", "Jan 22","Jan 22", "Feb 22","Feb 22", "Feb 22","Feb 22", "Feb 22","Feb 22")
Long_date <- c("1/1/2022", "1/1/2022", "1/1/2022", "1/1/2022", "1/1/2022", "1/1/2022", "2/1/2022", "2/1/2022", "2/1/2022", "2/1/2022","2/1/2022", "2/1/2022")
```

Category <- c("Original", "Discount", "Final","Original", "Discount", "Final","Original", "Discount", "Final","Original", "Discount", "Final")
Amount <- c(100, 20, 80, 90, 12, 78, 115,40, 75, 60, 15,55)
df_final <- data.frame(Short_Name, Long_Name, Short_date, Long_date, Category, Amount)

Answer (score 2):

One option - get the `diff`erence between the two rows of 'Amount' for the grouping columns and bind the summarised output with the original data and `arrange` the rows

```
library(dplyr)# version >= 1.1.0
df_original %>%
  filter(Category %in% c("Original", "Discount")) %>% 
   arrange(across(Short_Name:Long_date), Category == "Original") %>%
  reframe(Category = "Final", Amount = diff(Amount), 
 .by = c(Short_Name, Long_Name, Short_date, Long_date)) %>% 
 bind_rows(df_original, .) %>% 
 arrange(Short_Name, Long_Name, Short_date, Long_date)
```

-output

```
  Short_Name Long_Name Short_date Long_date Category Amount
1          BE   BELGIUM     Feb 22  2/1/2022 Original    120
2          BE   BELGIUM     Feb 22  2/1/2022 Discount     40
3          BE   BELGIUM     Feb 22  2/1/2022    Final     80
4          BE   BELGIUM     Jan 22  1/1/2022 Original    100
5          BE   BELGIUM     Jan 22  1/1/2022 Discount     20
6          BE   BELGIUM     Jan 22  1/1/2022    Final     80
7          DE   GERMANY     Feb 22  2/1/2022 Original     80
8          DE   GERMANY     Feb 22  2/1/2022 Discount     15
9          DE   GERMANY     Feb 22  2/1/2022    Final     65
10         DE   GERMANY     Jan 22  1/1/2022 Original     90
11         DE   GERMANY     Jan 22  1/1/2022 Discount     10
12         DE   GERMANY     Jan 22  1/1/2022    Final     80
```

---

Or use `add_row` in `group_modify`

```
library(tibble)
df_original %>%
  group_by(across(Short_Name:Long_date)) %>%
  group_modify(~ .x %>% 
  add_row(Category = "Final", 
  Amount = .x$Amount[.x$Category == "Original"] - 
     .x$Amount[.x$Category == "Discount"])) %>%
  ungroup
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 12 × 6
   Short_Name Long_Name Short_date Long_date Category Amount
   <chr>      <chr>     <chr>      <chr>     <chr>     <dbl>
 1 BE         BELGIUM   Feb 22     2/1/2022  Original    120
 2 BE         BELGIUM   Feb 22     2/1/2022  Discount     40
 3 BE         BELGIUM   Feb 22     2/1/2022  Final        80
 4 BE         BELGIUM   Jan 22     1/1/2022  Original    100
 5 BE         BELGIUM   Jan 22     1/1/2022  Discount     20
 6 BE         BELGIUM   Jan 22     1/1/2022  Final        80
 7 DE         GERMANY   Feb 22     2/1/2022  Original     80
 8 DE         GERMANY   Feb 22     2/1/2022  Discount     15
 9 DE         GERMANY   Feb 22     2/1/2022  Final        65
10 DE         GERMANY   Jan 22     1/1/2022  Original     90
11 DE         GERMANY   Jan 22     1/1/2022  Discount     10
12 DE         GERMANY   Jan 22     1/1/2022  Final        80
```

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately there are many more categories than 'Original' and 'Discount' and randomly organised so [2:1] would not work I think?

Comment: I get Error in ungroup(.) : could not find function "ungroup"